# How to get only the last aggregated value for a window?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I would like to aggregate a Kafka topic with a tumbling window and get only the last aggregated value for each window.

With the code, pasted below, the aggregated value is updated each time a new event arrives. So I get as many aggregated values as number of incoming events. I would like to have a topic with only last aggregated value for each window. Is it possible to achieve that (with ksqldb)?

```sql
CREATE TABLE all_pieces_tumbling AS
SELECT ResourceID, SUM(Value)
FROM all_pieces_stream
WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 1 MINUTE)
WHERE EventType = 23
GROUP BY ResourceID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EMIT FINAL` instead of `EMIT CHANGES` to only get the "final result".

Be aware about the "data driven" nature of `EMIT FINAL` though: [KSQLDB Emit Final does not return any value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68766847/ksqldb-emit-final-does-not-return-any-value)